# How to find value of each branch

Tags: complex-analysis, exponentiation

There is this question about the multi value operation of 
$(z-i)^{3/4}$ where it ask me to find the value of each branch when $z=1$. How do i approach it?

Thanks all..

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find the absolute value and argument of your $u=z-i$ number (for $z=1$ it will be $|u|=\sqrt2$ and $\phi=-\frac{\pi}{4}$)

Now you just have to use the formula

$$\left(u^{\frac{a}{b}}\right)_k = |u|^{\frac{a}{b}}\left(\cos \frac{a\phi + 2k\pi}{b}+i\sin\frac{a\phi + 2k\pi}{b}\right)$$
for $k=0,1,...,b-1$

Comment: thanks..but how do i express it in exponential form?

Comment: My previous ans is like.. 2^(3/8) e^i(21pi/16) e^(3(pi)ki/2) { 1, e^((-pi/2)I), e^((pi/2)i), e^((pi)i) } where k is real. But im not sure whether is it correct anot

Comment: The exponential form of $x$ is $\exp(\ln|x|+i\arg(x))$. In this case $|x|=|z-i|^{a/b}$ and $\arg(x)=\frac{a\phi+2k\pi}{b}$